# API versioning in Asp.net Web API 2 Query string parameter versioning

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I want to implement Query string parameter versioning in my Web API 2

Installed nuget package : Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/v{version}/default/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { Controllers="Default", Version="1.0", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

**Controller**

```
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
    [ApiVersion("1.0", Deprecated = true)]
    //[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    public class DefaultController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent("GET: Default Test message")
            };
        } 

        //This action mapped to Version 2.0
        [HttpPost,MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetProduct(Product item)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, item.Name);
            // Implementation not shown...
        }
    }
```

I want to access API using URI: api/v2.0/default/GetProduct

but, getting Message No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Comment: Why the `GetProduct` action is a `[HttpPost]` request?

Comment: GetProduct is action name and the method type required use is [HttpPost] so, GetProduct is just named (It could be anything).

Answer (score 0):

Your question says that you want to version by query string, but the code and example demonstrate that you want to version by URL segment. You might want to clarify your question. I'm going with the assumption you meant URL segment.

The reason this is not working is because you have not applied the **ApiVersionRouteConstraint**. As defined, the `{version}` route parameter is being treated as a plain old string, which will not work.

The correct setup is:

```cs
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/v{version}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Default", id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { version = new ApiVersionRouteConstraint() },
);
```

You cannot have default values unless they are at the end of the template. That means that `{Version="1.0"}` will have no effect and can be omitted. The name `version` can be whatever you want as long as it matches the name specified in the template.